# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2})^{k} \left(1-\frac{(-1)^k}{2}\right)$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2})^{k} \left(1-\frac{(-1)^k}{2}\right)$ converges.

I tried to show this by using the ration test:

I have: $$\frac{(\frac{1}{2})^{k+1} \left(1-\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{2}\right)}{(\frac{1}{2})^{k} \left(1-\frac{(-1)^k}{2}\right)}$$

Now assuming $k = 2n, n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$\frac{(\frac{1}{2})^{k+1} \left(1-\frac{(-1)}{2}\right)}{(\frac{1}{2})^{k} \left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{(\frac{1}{2})^{k+1} \frac{3}{2}}{(\frac{1}{2})^{k+1}}=\frac{3}{2}$$

So after the ratio test this series does not converge absolutely and therefore doesn't converge. How can this be, if I plug in the limit of the series into mathematica I get a limit of $\frac{7}{6}$. Is it wrong to assume that k is even?

Comment: Yes. In fact, your series converges. You can use the Comparison Test here, applied to $\sum (3/2)(1/2)^k$.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a valid method, but, if we find the sum of the even and odd terms, then new series is convergent.

Comment: Ok but is the ratio test that I have applied, incorrect?

Comment: Yes, it is incorrect. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#The_test), which seems relevant. You would need to show the $\liminf$ of the ratios exceeds $1$ to show divergence. But that isn't the case here; in fact, the Ratio Test will not work at all here, I believe.

Comment: Thank you. I still don't really understand why I should use $\sum (3/2)(1/2)^k$ for the comparison test, can you elaborate on that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show convergence, it suffices to make an appropriate comparison with another series whose terms are at least as large as those of the given series (i.e., comparison test).  If $a_k = \bigl(\frac{1}{2}\bigr)^k \bigl(1 - \frac{(-1)^k}{2}\bigr)$, then it is obvious that $a_k > 0$ for all $k$.  Then consider $$b_k = \frac{3}{2} \biggl(\frac{1}{2}\biggr)^k \ge a_k$$ and show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k$ is convergent by explicitly evaluating the sum.  Therefore, since $0 < a_k \le b_k$ for all $k \ge 1$, then $0 < \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k < \infty$, and the given sum converges.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2})^{k} \left(1-\frac{(-1)^k}{2}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2})^{k} +\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-\frac{1}{2})^{k+1}=1-\frac13.$$
Two convergent geometric series.